# How to refer to cells in other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a workbook contains several sheets. And i'm trying to use cell value that present in other sheet . How do i refer or use cell value in other sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've entered an equals sign into your formula box, you can then click any other cell, including cells in other sheets, to reference them, and they will be referenced automatically. If the sheet name is one word then it looks like this:

```
Sheet2!A1
```

Otherwise, if the sheet name is more than one word, it has single quotes around it:

```
'My Sheet'!A1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
=Sheet3!H14
```

or

```
='Sheet 3'!H14
```

if the sheet name includes embedded spaces.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. Sheet name i'm trying to use cell value contains spaces like **Sample Work Sheet ex** If i specify **Sample Work Sheet ex!H20** it is poping up file open dialog and displaying Like **#NAME?**.

Answer (score 0):

Use the form:

```
='Worksheetname'!cellname
```

where this formula goes in the cell you want your new value, and worksheet name and cell name are the sheet name and cell you want to take from.

e.g.

```
='Sheet1'!A1
```

would get the cell A1 from worksheet Sheet1

Answer (score 0):

Named ranges for individual cells or ranges of cells are valid throughout a workbook if the name defined with Defined Names under FORMULAS is chosen to be of Scope: Workbook.